# what is app? why we use csom and rest instead of app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm new to share point 2013.I am confused for these 3 why apps rest csom.when we use of these 3.can you please explain?

Comment: sorry, but this question is too broad. There are loads of sites explaining this. And to learn SharePoint it firstly would be better to book some trainings.

Comment: What do you actually want to implement? Apps or Rest API's? Please be concise about your question.

Comment: @sures Don't forget to mark the helpful answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

### What is an App?

In SharePoint 2013, everything in a SharePoint site is an app. SharePoint app or (App for SharePoint) is mainly a web application, a stand-alone piece of functionality that interacts with SharePoint via the Client-Side Object Model (CSOM), the REST and JavaScript API.  App cannot contain any server side code which is used in traditional SharePoint farm and sandboxed solution development. App code does not reside on the same server as SharePoint, rather it executes in the client browser or in IIS or in the cloud, thereby making the app loosely coupled with SharePoint. This enables developers to extend the capabilities of SharePoint sites without gaining full-trust access to the SharePoint farm. App is granted permission to SharePoint via OAuth. A key feature of app is that it can be developed using any programming language and technology such as HTML, JavaScript, .NET, PHP, or Java. App is published to a public marketplace or a corporate app catalog from where users can download or purchase it. App is easy to find in app store, install, use, manage, upgrade and uninstall.

App can be developed on both SharePoint Online and in On-Premise offerings. App use the following three types of deployment models.

**SharePoint-Hosted** – In the SharePoint-hosted deployment type model, a new isolated subweb known as app web is created under the parent site called the host web,  for hosting app. The app web keeps all the app content such as lists, workflows, pages, out-of-webparts and so on. The app code runs in the client browser which can use only HTML and JavaScript with CSOM / REST API and not any server side code.

**Auto-Hosted** (No longer possible to create) – In this cloud model, though the app is developed for SharePoint but the app code resides outside of the SharePoint on Microsoft Windows Azure in the background, which can also have access to Microsoft SQL Azure database for managing data. The app is automatically deployed to Windows Azure and SharePoint creates a cloud-hosted app on your behalf. Auto-hosted model is supported on SharePoint Online only unlike the other deployment models.

**Provider-Hosted** –  The Provider-hosted deployment model is almost same as Auto-hosted model, the only difference is that the app code resides in an external domain or server i.e. your own hosting environment which may not be necessarily be windows-based. The app code can be written in any programming language and technology like PHP, .NET or Java. In this scenario, SharePoint acts only as launching pad for the external app.

Refer the following link for more information on apps. Apps for SharePoint Overview –  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx

**Difference between using App and CSOM or RestApi**

SharePoint apps are the customize components in which we can use REST API and JSOM code to fulfill our business logic.

[REST API](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) and [JSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) are the code techniques to manipulate SharePoint data in client side.

e.g
We can add CSOM or RestApi code in Content Editor Web part but we can't put the SharePoint App into Content Editor Web Part.

**Reference:**

- [The difference between webpart and add-ins](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193309/the-difference-between-webpart-and-add-ins/193317#193317)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/what_is_an_app_app_part_web_part/2014/01/31/what-is-an-app-app-part-web-part/
- http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/256364/SharePoint-2013-s-App-Model-vs-SharePoint-Web-Parts

Comment: If its helpful to you then please mark this answer as accepted so it will be helpful to others.